# Printing list in least amount of rows and columns

Tags: python, function, primes

Code for finding primes:

```
def findPrimes(n):

    prime_list = list()
    for number in range(1, n + 1):
        prime = True
        for i in range(2, number):
            if(number % i == 0):
                prime = False
        if prime:
            prime_list.append(number)

    return prime_list
```

Code for making primes list neatly:

```
def displayPrimes(number, rows = 50):

    table_list = [[] for _ in range(rows)]
    primes = findPrimes(number)

    for index, item in enumerate(primes):
        row_index = index % rows
        table_list[row_index].append("%6d" % item)

    table_str = "\n".join(["\t".join(i) for i in table_list])

    return table_str
print(displayPrimes(4027))
```

Code for finding twin primes:

```
def findTwinPrimes(n):
     prime = [True for i in range(n + 2)] 
     p = 2

     while (p * p <= n + 1): 

        # If prime[p] is not changed,  
        # then it is a prime 
        if (prime[p] == True): 

            # Update all multiples of p 
            for i in range(p * 2, n + 2, p): 
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1

    # check twin prime numbers 
    # display the twin prime numbers 
        for p in range(2, n-1): 
            if prime[p] and prime[p + 2]: 
                print("(",p,",", (p + 2), ")" ,end='')

print(findTwinPrimes(4027))
```

Code for making the twin primes display neatly.
Issue is that it says:

> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Wouldn't this work since I have same data in code that uses to display primes, its just displaying the list neatly?

```
def displayTwinPrimes(number, rows = 52):

    table_list = [[] for _ in range(rows)]
    twinPrimes = findTwinPrimes

    for index, item in enumerate(twinPrimes):
        row_index = index % rows
        table_list[row_index].append("%6d" % item)

    table_str = "\n".join(["\t".join(i) for i in table_list])    

    return table_str

print(displayTwinPrimes(4027))
```

Comment: `twinPrimes = findTwinPrimes` <- You forgot to call the function

Comment: also its giving me an error that func isnt iterable ive never seen this

Answer (score 0):

```
twinPrimes = findTwinPrimes
```

This *refers* to the findTwinPrimes function, but does not *call* it, because there are no parentheses on the end.

If you want to *call* the function, you need parentheses:

```
twinPrimes = findTwinPrimes(some_argument_here)
```

Comment: got it, i had to put in 4027 as argumnt, now it still isnt prinitng them in a neatly way where are all the parentheses line up just like how it prints it out in for just the findPrime fun https://imgur.com/a/lqIZsee

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor **code for finding twin numbers** as below.

This method returns *list of twin primes tuple* as i.e `[(3,5),(5,7), ...]`

```
def findTwinPrimes(n):
    prime = [True for i in range(n + 2)]
    p = 2
    twin_primes = []
    while (p * p <= n + 1):

        # If prime[p] is not changed,
        # then it is a prime
        if (prime[p] == True):

            # Update all multiples of p
            for i in range(p * 2, n + 2, p):
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1

    # check twin prime numbers
    # display the twin prime numbers
    for p in range(2, n - 1):
        if prime[p] and prime[p + 2]:
            twin_primes.append((p, (p + 2)))
            print("(", p, ",", (p + 2), ")", end='')

    return twin_primes  # this returns twin_primes as list of tuples i.e [(3,5),(5,7), ...]
```

Also you need to refurbish your `displayTwinPrimes` method as below:

```
def displayTwinPrimes(number, rows = 52):

    table_list = [[] for _ in range(rows)]
    twinPrimes = findTwinPrimes(number)

    for index, item in enumerate(twinPrimes):
        row_index = index % rows
        table_list[row_index].append(item)

    table_str = "\n".join(["\t".join(["(%6d, %6d)" % (p[0],p[1]) for p in i]) for i in table_list])

    return table_str
```

Comment: would there be a way to make numbers printed by least amount of columns? or decide how many columns i want instead of rows?